# Proof of partition of natural numbers

Tags: set-partition

I have a set $A_n$ = $ \{2^i(2n-1): i \in \mathbb{N} \cup {0} \}$

It is said that the set  $P = $ $\{A1, A2, A3,...\}$ partitions the natural numbers.

I am attempting to solve this by the definition of a partition, I can see that no $An = \emptyset$, but I can't see how the union of all the $An$'s would give $\mathbb{N}$ can anyone help?

Comment: $A_n$ contains all positive integers of the form $(2n-1)2^k$.  This means that each element in $A_n$ will have $(2n-1)$ as its largest odd factor.

Comment: Each positive integer is a power of $2$ times an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get some intuition is to take some numbers and see which set they belong to.  For example, $12=2^2\cdot 3 \in A_3$  You divide out all the factors of $2$ and are left with an odd number $N$.  You let $N=2n-1, n=\frac 12(N+1)$ and that is the set $A_n$ it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A_1$. This is the set $\{2^i\}$, which contains the elements $1,2,4,8,16,\cdots$. Now consider $A_2$, which is $2^i\times3$ which contains the elements $3,6,12,24,\cdots$. Do something similar for $A_4$ and so on.  You should see that the least element of $A_{k}$ is always the $k$th odd number, which is $2k-1$ , and so you can generate every odd element of $\mathbb{N}$ in such a way. By the definition of the set, we can multiply every element by $2$, which makes every even number. Now you need only formalise this proof.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the statement you've made on the 3rd line and how that shows I can generate every natural number.

Comment: Hi, so what I was saying is that for the set $A_n$, the elements are $2^i(2n-1)$. For $n=2$ we have elements of $2^i\times{3}$ as $I$ ranges over the non-negative integers. Substitute in $i=0,1,2,\cdots$. This generates the terms $3,6,12,24,\cdots$. For $A_4$ we have $2^i\times{5}$, so we get $5,10,20,\cdots$. As such we will get every odd number as the minimum element of $A_k$. As such we will get every even number as their sum, which is contained in the union - we have every odd number, and we can multiply each by any power of $2$, so all the naturals are achieved.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me, that makes more sense now. So is it just a fact that we can generate any even natural number by multiplying a particualr odd natural number by a particular power of 2?

Comment: Yes, so long as your statement is refined. Since we generate every odd number, without loss of generality including some odd number $n$, we also get $2n,4n,\cdots$ and by varying $n$ we get every even number as well. A good way to think about this is the integers on a number line - how do we get 28, for example? It would be $28\rightarrow 14\rightarrow 7\rightarrow 2(3)+1$. Does this make sense?